# Round the labels on bars of animated barplot in gganimate?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I want to round the labels on each corresponding bar. Currently when animation is in transition it show many decimal places:

Data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(TIME = c(2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L), GEO = c("Belgium", 
"Denmark", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Austria", "Finland", "Sweden", 
"England and Wales", "Scotland", "Norway", "Belgium", "Denmark", 
"France", "Netherlands", "Finland", "Sweden", "England and Wales", 
"Scotland", "Norway", "Switzerland", "Belgium", "Denmark", "France", 
"Luxembourg", "Netherlands", "Finland", "Sweden", "England and Wales", 
"Norway", "Switzerland", "Belgium", "Denmark", "France", "Luxembourg", 
"Netherlands", "Finland", "Sweden", "England and Wales", "Norway", 
"Switzerland", "Denmark", "France", "Luxembourg", "Austria", 
"Finland", "Sweden", "England and Wales", "Scotland", "Norway", 
"Switzerland"), Totals = c(5286.56, 8757, 4338.07, 7492.47, 3896.74, 
3947.06, 8018.07, 5874.61, 5295.17, 5067.58, 5013.71, 8689.99, 
3547.7, 4101.23, 3906.24, 7580.88, 5267.49, 3541.64, 5057.55, 
4687.57, 5103.1, 8108.56, 3636.92, 3694.94, 4139.11, 3631.12, 
7488.32, 4636.97, 4853.56, 5436.76, 4979.9, 7254.61, 4002.94, 
4848.09, 3680.72, 3620.9, 7189.69, 4582.57, 4201.47, 4527.36, 
6407.65, 4226.66, 4137.27, 3426.35, 3393.87, 6683.56, 5047.98, 
3218.93, 3050.54, 3767.67), ordering = c(6, 1, 8, 3, 10, 9, 2, 
4, 5, 7, 5, 1, 9, 7, 8, 2, 3, 10, 4, 6, 4, 1, 9, 8, 7, 10, 2, 
6, 5, 3, 3, 1, 8, 4, 9, 10, 2, 5, 7, 6, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1, 3, 
9, 10, 6))

testp <- mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x = -ordering, y = Totals, fill = GEO)) +
    geom_col(width = 0.8, position = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes(-ordering, y=0, label = GEO, hjust=0)) +       #country label
    geom_text(aes(-ordering, y=Totals, label = Totals, hjust=0)) + # value label
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
    labs(y = "Offences per thousand inhabitants",
         x = "Countries", title = "Crime Data for European Countries {closest_state}") +
    transition_states(TIME, transition_length = 10, state_length = 14, wrap = FALSE)

animate(testp,fps = 30,  width = 600, height = 500, nframes = 270,
 start_pause = 30, end_pause = 30, renderer = gifski_renderer("gganim_test.gif"))
```

Output:

[image: gganim_test]

I also tried by setting `labels = round(Totals,1)` in `geom_text` but no change in animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the labels via `scales::number` will do the trick:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(dplyr)

testp <- mydf %>% ggplot(aes(x = -ordering, y = Totals, fill = GEO)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.8, position = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(-ordering, y = 0, label = GEO, hjust = 0)) + # country label
  geom_text(aes(-ordering, y = Totals, label = scales::number(Totals, acc = 1), hjust = 0)) + # value label
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank())  +
  labs(
    y = "Offences per thousand inhabitants",
    x = "Countries", title = "Crime Data for European Countries {closest_state}"
  ) +
  transition_states(TIME, transition_length = 10, state_length = 14, wrap = FALSE)

testa <- testp +
  transition_states(TIME, transition_length = 10, state_length = 14, wrap = FALSE)

animate(testp,
   fps = 30, width = 600, height = 500, nframes = 10,
   start_pause = 30, end_pause = 30, renderer = gifski_renderer("gganim_test.gif")
)
```

[image]